# Not able to display image due to apostrophe symbols in angulat6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6, angular-material-6

I am using angular 6

**My Requirement**

In my details product page there is an image section  if the user keep the mouse hover to that image it must Zoomed.

**Problem**

Some of that product image name contains special character like ',' ,'-'. if this symbols contains means that product not displayed.

**Code**

**HTML**

```
<mat-card *ngIf="zoomImage" class="zoom-viewer mat-elevation-z18" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + zoomImage + ')'}"></mat-card>
```

**Component**

```
public getProductById(id){
    this.appService.getProductById(id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.product = data;
      this.image = data.images[0].medium.replace(/\s/g,'%20');
      this.zoomImage = data.images[0].big.replace(/\s/g,'%20').replace(/'/g,'%20');
      setTimeout(() => { 
        // .slice(1, 5)
        this.config.observer = true;
      });
    });
  }
```

I don't know what is the mistake in that so please help me to do this.

Comment: Remove the quotes from your file names maybe ?

Comment: So are `this.image` and `this.zoomImage` supposed to be URLs? Then why are you manipulating characters in them in such a wrong way? `%20` is the URL escape for a normal space character - not for _every_ white space character, and not for `'` either. Maybe you should try proper URL encoding? `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: I tried your example @op -   zoomImage = "images/aa,bb-cc.png"; and it is working just fine. Give us an example what the  zoomImage  looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully reproduced your problem and my solution is this:

I created an image with name **aa,`bb`-'cc'.png**

my test ts component:

```
  zoomImage = JSON.stringify("images/aa,`bb`-'cc'.png");
```

my test html:

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" 

[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + zoomImage + ')'}"></div>
```

You can also make a wrapper function to apply stringify easily like that:

```
  // Only for example function
  decodeImageName(funkyImageName) {
    return JSON.stringify(funkyImageName);
  }
```

and in your template: [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + decodeImageName(zoomImage) + ')'}"

---

So basically you can try to parse your weird image name with JSON.stringify like that - **JSON.stringify("Your'Weird`Image-n'a'm'e.png")**